# More Sessions than Pageviews in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I track the usage for my company's app, and we have a website counterpart to the app.

The issue I'm running across is that the sessions for the website are 3 to 4 times higher than my pageviews. I'm not sure why this is happening. Technically every session should have a pageview, but right now every session is showing 1/2 a pageview or 1/4 of a pageview, which doesn't make sense.

Has anyone else run across this issue? Is this data even correct?

Comment: Hi Michelle, did you manage to fix this? I encounter the same issue. For a website I've got ~250 sessions, ~220 users and then ~50 pageviews. Doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not breaking the data by Hit or Page level data.

Here is the reason: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en